# Django Forms - Change widget attributes

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-2.1

I want to define a `class` attribute for the `<option/>` tags within a django `ChoiceField`, how can I do that?

I tried to set the widget class, and specifying an attribute like so, in **forms.py**:

```
field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')], widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

And rendering inside my `template.html` like this:

`{{ form.field }}`

The output is:

```
<select name="field" class="form-control" id="id_field">
   <option value="1">foo</option>
   <option value="2">bar</option>
</select>
```

And what I want to have is this:

```
<select name="field" class="form-control" id="id_fields">
   <option class="form-control" value="1">foo</option>
   <option class="form-control" value="2">bar</option>
</select>
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Obviously not very helpful, but last minute you can go with JS ;)

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde I know, but I would like to know if there is a way to do this in Django...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to subclass the `Select` widget and set `option_inherits_attrs` to True:

```
class CustomSelect(forms.Select):
    option_inherits_attrs = True
```

Then use your custom widget when creating the form:

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    items = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')],
        widget=CustomSelect(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control'}
        )
```

Comment: Wow, it's that simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may create a **[Template Tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/)** and write a custom template field. It's the best option if you want to reuse attributes.

> The app should contain a templatetags directory, at the same level as **models.py**, **views.py**, etc. If this doesn’t already exist, create it - don’t forget the **__init__.py** file to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package.

Create this structure inside your app's folder

[image]

Inside **filters.py**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='addclass')
def addclass(value, arg):
    return value.as_widget(attrs={'class': arg})
```

Add `{% load filters %}` to your **template.html**, before `{% block content %}`

That's how you apply your filter:

```
{{form.field|addclass:'form-control'}}
```

Now you should forget about adding classes to your HTML elements inside **forms.py**

---

If you disliked the Template Tag way or maybe are just looking for a low-cost temporary solution, you should take a look at this link.

[Another way of solving the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50534519/6651730)

Comment: I could use the Template Tag method, but it still doesn't apply a `class` property to the children `<option>` elements, only to the parent `<select>`, which is the same as specifying the properties for the widget